# Release the Python import lock from a thread you do not control & do not have access to

Tags: python, c++, dll, code-injection, cpython

So, I'm injecting a DLL into a Cython application in order to extend its functionality. I am doing this using the following code:
Note: using Python 2.7; uses the old ModuleNoBlock scheme

```
PyGILState_STATE sMain = PyGILState_Ensure();
PyObject* mHook = PyImport_ImportModuleNoBlock("hookmodule");
PyGILState_Release(sMain);
```

Now, when I inject the DLL into the application and print errors, I get the following:

```
ImportError: Failed to import hookmodule because the import lockis held by another thread.
```

I found the source to the imp module [here](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/trunk/Python/import.c)

However `_PyImport_ReleaseLock(void)` only releases the lock if you call it from the same thread where the lock was acquired.

Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. Use

```
_PyImport_ReInitLock(void)
```

before importing